# How will JWST see beginning of universe?

Tags: space-telescope, james-webb-telescope

The light that is supposed to come from far away distance galaxy, that will reach James Webb Telescope, won't it have already passed earth? BBC puts out this explanation in [this](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-59476869) article.

[image]

Won't the galaxy/star formation light have already crossed us all the while our life was evolving on earth? I just wonder, hypothetically, if JWST had been already there (1 billion years ago) in the place it is going to be there, and looking at space it is looking at, what would it have seen?

Comment: Why do you think it would have crossed us?

Comment: You may have better luck on [astronomy.stackexchange.com](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you are confused by direction of the images in the illustration